# Vulnerability issue - Security.allowDomain(*) - Flow player

Tags: security, flowplayer

We are using a Flow player control on website to view video's. We are able to view the video properly.
But when we ran a Website Security Vulnerability Test , a possible threat was detected.

Thread -- Security.allowDomain("*") is used in a Flash movie
http://abc.com/JScripts/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf

The flow player version is 3.1.5

Can anyone tell what needs to be done to handle this security threat?
Below is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    flowplayer("player", "../JScripts/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", {
        clip: {url: '<%= getVideoUrl() %>', autoPlay: false,autoBuffering: true},
        plugins:
            {
                controls:
                {
                    url: '../JScripts/flowplayer.controls-3.1.5.swf',
                    all: false, play: true, stop: true, scrubber: true,volume: true,
                    mute: true, time: true, tooltips: {buttons: true, fullscreen: 'Enter fullscreen mode'}
                }
            }
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: How do you run a vulnerability on a website?  That is baffling.

Comment: Hi Rook.. I was referring to a Website Security Vulnerability Test... Do you any answer to my question?

Answer (score 1):

That is just saying that you are allowing all domains to run your script and to use them properly, say someone wants to run your swf script from another site. "*" part means every domain is allowed to do that. the vulnerability assessment says this is an issue because all domains have access to your variables and objects in your swf file, however with automatic vulnerability assessments you typically get a lot of false positives. If you are still concerned take a look at the docs at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge issue. In many cases it means that attacker can:

1. Host attacker SWF on any domain
2. Load your SWF into his
3. Make user load hist SWF (e.g. in invisible frame)
4. Execute HTTP requests to your domain with all ambient user credentials attached (cookies or HTTP Authentication) via your vulnerable SWF

Imagine you have http://www.abc.com/mail that is accessible using cookie or HTTP Auth. Attacker may be able to load all that data and send it to his server.

- Solution 1: remove all allowDomain() calls
- Solution 2: allow only
  trusted or controlled that attacker can't upload SWF to
- Solution 3:
  host vulnerable SWF on other server that doesn't use ambient
  credentials